# Can wildcards be used on tablenames for a GRANT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

Is it possible in MySQL to do a GRANT to a user on a set of tables within a database, e.g. to allow CREATE AND DROP ing of some table names but not others?

Neither of these seem to work:

```
GRANT SELECT ON  `testdb`.`%_testing` TO  'wildcardtest'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON  `testdb`.`testing%` TO  'wildcardtest'@'localhost';
```

and the MySQL manual doesn't seem to give an answer either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only wildcard that works in the GRANT statement is *

```
GRANT SELECT ON `testdb`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'privilegeduser'@'localhost';
```

It's all or one; there's no facility for dynamic matching of table names to granted privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can separate table names with commas but can't use wildcards in a GRANT.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty database .
Give it access to the original database ( use a user who allready have access to original database )
in this new database 
CREATE VIEW test as SELECT * from originaldatabase.tablename
WHERE conditions...

Then give test user access to NewDatabase whith 
GRANT select on NewDatabase.* to 'testuser'@'localhost'

Then only create views for the tables you want testuser to access.

Also remember you can do a USER() in the WHERE part of the view:

example:
create view test as 
select * from original.customer where mysql_user = USER()

In the original.customer you must then have a column 'mysql_user'
and every row the test user is allowed to see must have testuser@localhost as a entry

The testuser will see all the created views as tables in the database 'test'

Comment: I do not see where this answer involves wildcards (see question title).

Comment: @syck I asume that the question is how to limit a user to only some of the tables in the original database. When only creating 'views' for the tables that are to be used, the end user can only access those in the NewDatabase.

Comment: As stated in the question title, the OP wanted to know how to use wildcards to give access to certain tables. Granting on single tables (or creating views for them) is not the problem, but sometimes not appropriate. Think of scientific data, which is sometimes organized in hundreds or thousands of similar tables.