# Grant privileges to certain mysql database tables quickly by using "*"?

Tags: mysql

Is there a possibility to do something like this?

```
GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON  `database`.`prefix_*` TO  'user'@'localhost';
```

Which allows me to set permissions quickly for every table that starts with "prefix_"

Comment: Yes, but using `%` as the wildcard, not `*`, and backslash-escape the `_` because that is itself a wildcard too.  `prefix\_%`

Comment: When I use the backslash-escape command I get: `#1103 - Incorrect table name 'prefix\_%'`

Comment: Does any table with `prefix_` currently exist?

Comment: Yes, but it's on an old test-machine - did this wildcard situation exist from older versions, or only on newer versions? I can grant access to all tables with the "prefix_" when I specify the full table name, just not with the wildcard.

Comment: Are you quoting with backticks as in your example? Are you granting as root, or a user with only limited specific grants on that database? I just tested and could get this to work correctly.

Comment: Hmm, wait - the MySQL docs only specify that wildcards work in _database_ names, not mentioning table names. It works in a table name for me on MariaDB, but regular MySQL may not support that. I reopened.... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Comment: Seems like it's all or nothing on _tablenames_ -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489577/776264

Comment: It does appear that way for regular MySQL  :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%` instead of `*`

```
GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON  `database`.`prefix\_%` TO  'user'@'localhost';
```

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords):

> The `“_”` and `“%”` wildcards are permitted when specifying database names
>   in GRANT statements that grant privileges at the global or database
>   levels. This means, for example, that if you want to use a “_”
>   character as part of a database name, you should specify it as “_” in
>   the GRANT statement, to prevent the user from being able to access
>   additional databases matching the wildcard pattern;

Comment: As stated by the documentation, you can only use `%` in database names, NOT table names.